# Unable to print CSV file

Tags: c++, csv, iostream

The following code compiles fine so there's no syntax errors. I am having trouble printing out the CSV file I read into this bit of code. I am not sure what is going on as this is a standard procedure, but would appreciate some input as to how to resolve this. I'd like to be able to print out the content of `s` on the console. Can you see why `s` is not printing on the console? Am I missing something?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include<iterator>

struct field_reader: std::ctype<char> {

    field_reader(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table() {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask>
            rc(table_size, std::ctype_base::mask());

        rc[';'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};


struct Stud{
    double VehicleID;
    double FinancialYear;
    double VehicleType;
    double Manufacturer;
    double ConditionScore;


    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Stud &s) {
        return is >> s.VehicleID >> s.FinancialYear >> s.VehicleType >>      s.Manufacturer >> s.ConditionScore;
    }

    // we'll also add an operator<< to support printing these out:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Stud const &s) {
        return os << s.VehicleID  << "\t"
                  << s.FinancialYear << "\t"
                  << s.VehicleType    << "\t"
                  << s.Manufacturer   << "\t"
                  << s.ConditionScore;
    }
};

int main(){
// Open the file:
std::ifstream in("VehicleData_cs2v_1.csv");

// Use the ctype facet we defined above to classify `;` as white-space:
in.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new field_reader));

// read all the data into the vector:
std::vector<Stud> studs{(std::istream_iterator<Stud>(in)),
 std::istream_iterator<Stud>()};

// show what we read:
for (auto s : studs)
    std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Comment: ... and what's wrong? I think I've seen this code somewhere here today.

Comment: I'd like to be able to print out the content of s on the console, I didn't think it'd be that complicated to be honest. Can you see why s is not printing on the console? Am I missing something?

Comment: Compiles fine, but does it work? Print out the state of `in` and  the size of studs to see if you managed to read anything.

Comment: Do you get any error? Anyway, we don't have your input file, so we can't say. Place here an example of your input.

Comment: Change the declaration of the vector to: `static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> rc(classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size);`

Comment: Thanks user above me, your answer along with answer below by @user35443  worked perfectly, I will edit my question to show solution thanks guys

Comment: Don't edit the question to show the solution. Showing the solution is what the answers are for. If you want, you can add an answer of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Stud &s) {
    return is >> s.VehicleID >> s.FinancialYear >> s.VehicleType 
              >> s.Manufacturer >> s.ConditionScore;
}
```

Ignores the fact that the commas are present completely. The most primitive solution I could think of was

```
friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Stud &s) {
    char comma;
    return is >> s.VehicleID >> comma
              >> s.FinancialYear >> comma
              >> s.VehicleType >> comma
              >> s.Manufacturer >> comma
              >> s.ConditionScore;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I don't know what I am doing wrong but I just tried to copy paste that and see what printed out on the console but nothing.
I'd like to be able to print out the content of s, I didn't think it'd be that complicated to be honest. Can you see why s is not printing on the console? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hello, thanks everyone that replied, the answer was a mix of this answer  along with the answer by  @0x499602D2